# Scanning and negative integer literals in OCaml

Tags: operators, ocaml, literals, lexical-analysis

According to the [OCaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lex.html), an integer literal can be negative. For instance, `-321` is a valid integer literal.

The manual also states that lexical ambiguities are resolved according to the *longest match rule*: when a character sequence can be decomposed into two tokens in several different ways, the decomposition retained is the one with the longest first token.

Thus the expression `8-3` should be decomposed into the two lexical symbols `8` and `-3` leading to a type error, and not into the three lexical symbols `8`, `-` and `3`, giving a binary operation. But the second interpretation is what I get when evaluating this expression in the toplevel.

Am I missing something from the manual, or is it really incomplete regarding this subject? If the later, the manual probably should be fixed.

Answer (score 5):

In the lexer level (lexer.mll) of OCaml syntax definition, integer literals are defined without `-` prefix. For example,

```
let decimal_literal =
  ['0'-'9'] ['0'-'9' '_']*

let int_literal =
  decimal_literal | hex_literal | oct_literal | bin_literal
```

The resolution of `-` sign is done in the parser (parser.mly) level. So that `8-3` can be parsed as `(8)-(3)` instead of `8 (-3)`. Sole `-3` is parsed as a negative integer constant also in the parser level. This is how things are implemented.

The exceptional handling of prefix `-` is explained at http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html#sec138 . The manual explains something different from the implementation, but it states the convention. I feel it needs not to be very precise to the implementation. You may create a ticket at http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/my_view_page.php if you feel it to be fixed.

Comment: Don't bother creating a ticket it won't be fixed. See http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=6015

Comment: In a note in the [ticket #6015](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=6015) mentioned in the previous comment, someone justifies that negative numeric literals are needed to correctly parse the list `[-1]`, because the `-` symbol can be a prefix or an infix operator, and the infix one has precedence over the other. That seems very odd.

Comment: If it was the case, the expression `- 8 - 3` would be parsed as `- (8 - 3)`, and not as `(-8) - (3)`.

Comment: Thus the justification for closing the bug as won't fix may be invalid.

Comment: At `parser.mly` in the implementation, the token `MINUS` has a lower precedence than the token `prec_unary_minus`, and the expressions related to the prefix and infix `-` operator are `expr MINUS expr` and `subtractive expr %prec prec_unary_minus`where `subtractive` may be `MINUS`. Clearly the prefix operator is given higher precedence than the infix operator. Thus the note on the ticket is wrong and the negative literal is not needed as was claimed there.